# tmp folder in apache is getting full with files named /tmp/php*. How can I find which session or file is creating them?

Tags: php, apache, owncloud, tmp

my server tmp folder (capacity of 4GB) gets full very fast (within a few hours). There are some small session files in there, but the ones which take up all the space are files named "php[UNIQUE_CODE]".

I already changed in php.ini both the "upload_tmp_dir" and "session.save_path" to another directory, but these "php*" files are still emerging. The session files are saved in the new directory.

I have owncloud and wordpress installed on the server since over a year, but this is something that occurs the last days.

How can I check which file or session is creating these large files on the tmp folder?

Thanks!
J

Comment: i have the same issue ? any one find out what is that files ?

Answer (score 2):

it is not related to session

these files are related to io
since i am using "fopen($filePath, 'rb')" in my code , these files are creating by system and will be delete automatically (if it has enough space on /tmp folder)

if you want to change /tmp for these type of file you can change below params in your .ini file and restart apache

upload_tmp_dir='/tmp2/'
sys_temp_dir='/tmp2/'

and be sure your folder has 777 + t permission , and user/group can be 'root'